# Use a defined function on list of lists in python

Tags: python, mapreduce

I have a defined function:

```
def map(id,txt):
   mapop= []
   words = txt.split()
   for word in words:
     tmp= (word,id,1)
     mapop.append(tmp)
   return mapop
```

I have tried to apply this function on my list of lists using many method but none of them work.

1. The below gives AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

   ```
   list(map(len,filtered_wordList))
   ```
2. This gives an TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'txt'

   ```
   [map(item) for item in filtered_wordList]
   ```
3. This gives an TypeError: map() takes 2 positional arguments but 89 were given

   ```
   mapped=[]
   for line in filtered_wordList:
      temp=map(*line)
   mapped.append(temp)
   ```

Could you please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: "I have tried to apply this function on my list of lists" - why? This function wasn't written to take a list of lists.

Comment: @user2357112 I want to know how to apply this function on atleast one of the list.

Comment: in addition to everything else, `map` is a [built-in Python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and while it's allowed to redefine it as you are doing here, it's generally a (very) bad idea

Comment: This function is written to take whatever the heck `id` was supposed to be, and a string. I don't know what's in your `filtered_wordlist`, but it's not whatever-`id`-was-supposed-to-be and a string.

Comment: `filtered_wordlist` seems to be a list of lists. Hence you might be ending up passing a list rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your function map like this:

```
text = 'Stack Overflow is great'
map(2, text)
```

It outputs:

```
[('Stack', 2, 1), ('Overflow', 2, 1), ('is', 2, 1), ('great', 2, 1)]
```

Your function takes in an `id` variable and a text (which should be a string). 
It splits the text on space like this:

```
['Stack', 'Overflow', 'is', 'great']
```

And loops over each word in this list and adds a tuple which includes the word, the id you passes and 1 to your `mapop` list like this:

```
('Stack', 2, 1)
```

After it loops over each word, it returns `mapop`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the immediate problem is that you're arguing with yourself: you haven't been consistent about what arguments your function should use -- whether the input text is a single sentence or a list of sentences.  I took the liberty of changing the function name.  Here's a suggested use that I think solves your problem.  You can reduce several of the statement blocks to a single line, but I expect the current version is more readable for you.

```
filtered_wordlist = [
    'Call me Ishmael',
    'The boy was odd',
    'They could only say it just "happened to happen" and was not very likely to happen again.'
]

def word_id(id,txt):
   mapop= []
   words = txt.split()
   for word in words:
     tmp= (word,id,1)
     mapop.append(tmp)
   return mapop 


lexicon = []
for id, sentence in enumerate(filtered_wordlist):
    lexicon.append(word_id(id, sentence))

print(lexicon)
```

Output (with extra line breaks for readability):

```
[('Call', 0, 1), ('me', 0, 1), ('Ishmael', 0, 1),
 ('The', 1, 1), ('boy', 1, 1), ('was', 1, 1), ('odd', 1, 1),
 ('They', 2, 1), ('could', 2, 1), ('only', 2, 1), ('say', 2, 1),
 ('it', 2, 1), ('just', 2, 1), ('"happened', 2, 1), ('to', 2, 1),
 ('happen"', 2, 1), ('and', 2, 1), ('was', 2, 1), ('not', 2, 1),
 ('very', 2, 1), ('likely', 2, 1), ('to', 2, 1), ('happen', 2, 1),
 ('again.', 2, 1)]
```